# AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, eclipse, classnotfound

I am running:

- OS X v10.8.4
- Eclipse 3.7.2
- Java 1.6
- Android minSdkVersion 17
- Android targetSdkVersion 17

But no dice. The compiler recognizes plain old `AbstractMap` declarations, but has no clue about `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` or `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`:

[image: bad compiler]

However, via command line (`javac 1.6.0_51`) the following does build and run:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;

public class Test {
   public static void main (String args[]) {
      AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry<String, String> entry =
          new AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry("key", "value");
      System.out.println(entry.getKey());
      System.out.println(entry.getValue());
   }
}
```

Also, Android Studio (I/O Preview) recognizes `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry`.

I have Build -> Clean'd, restarted Eclipse, rebooted the Mac. So something is wrong in my Eclipse setup. Help!

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are building with level 17 of the SDK? `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` was added in API level 9.

Comment: That was it, I forgot about the list in Project->Properties->Android.

Comment: If you want a little love I will accept it as an answer, otherwise I'll delete in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: Posted answer, glad it was that simple :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you *sure* you are building with level 17 of the SDK? `AbstractMap.SimpleImmutableEntry` was added in API level 9. That exact class caught me out too as I build with API level 8.